# SSH jump hosts error

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have trouble understanding a peculiar behavior of ssh jump hosts.
I have these configurations in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host bastion-server
  Hostname server.bastion.com
  ForwardAgent yes
  User user
Host internal-server
  Hostname 10.0.0.123
  User user2
Host *%via-bastion
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion-server -W $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f1):%p
```

when I try to connect using the command `ssh internal-server%via-bastion` it throws this error:

channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

However, when I define

```
Host bastion-server
  Hostname server.bastion.com
  ForwardAgent yes
  User user
Host internal-server
  Hostname 10.0.0.123
  User user2
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion-server -W %h:%p
```

and use `ssh internal-server` it works perfectly.

Any ideas as of why it happens?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, your proxy command expands to:

```
ssh bastion-server -W internal-server:22
```

In the second,

```
ssh bastion-server -W 10.0.0.123:22
```

The former doesn't work because your bastion server doesn't recognize the name `internal-server`.

(The translation doesn't happen client-side, because the client simply doesn't understand that it should look at `Host internal-server` when you run `ssh internal-server%via-bastion` – as far as it's concerned, those are entirely different names.)